# Inserting Line Break to the nearest space after a set of character length is set

Tags: vba, excel

I have come across this code(not mine), what it actually does is insert a Line break after a character length has been determined.

```
Public Function LFNearSpace(InputStr As String, CharCnt As Long)

Dim SplitStrArr() As Variant
Dim SplitCnt As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim Lcnt As Long
Dim Rcnt As Long
Dim OutputStr As String

'Split string into Array
ReDim SplitStrArr(Len(InputStr) - 1)
For i = 1 To Len(InputStr)
    SplitStrArr(i - 1) = Mid$(InputStr, i, 1)
Next

SplitCnt = 0
For c = LBound(SplitStrArr) To UBound(SplitStrArr)
    SplitCnt = SplitCnt + 1
    If SplitCnt = CharCnt Then
        'get count to space nearest to the left and right of word
        For i = c To LBound(SplitStrArr) Step -1
            If SplitStrArr(i) = " " Then
                Lcnt = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        For i = c To UBound(SplitStrArr)
            If SplitStrArr(i) = " " Then
                Rcnt = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        'add line feed to nearest space
        If (Rcnt - c) < (c - Lcnt) Then
            SplitStrArr(Lcnt) = Chr(10)
            SplitCnt = c - Lcnt
        ElseIf (Rcnt - c) = (c - Lcnt) Then
            SplitStrArr(Rcnt) = Chr(10)
            SplitCnt = c - Rcnt
        End If
    End If
Next c

'Finalize the output into a single string
LFNearSpace = Join(SplitStrArr, "")

End Function
```

**So here's my condition:
Column Width: 75
Font Name: Arial
Font Size: 9**

I am customizing it for a while to fit my conditions,as far as I can think of

Unfortunately, the function cuts(inserts line break) the word not in natural way for example: 
I call it like this, well if I change the 105 value the output changes but ***I wanted to create a solution why the output is similar to the image below.***

```
SomeStr = LFNearSpace(SomeStr, 105)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = SomeStr
```

[image]

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just format column 1 to Wrap Text?

Comment: I did but I wanted to eliminate the extra spaces created when autofit and wrap is applied, so I added line breaks to control the output when printed

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
With Columns(1)
    .ColumnWidth = 75
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.Size = 9
    .WrapText = True
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

below code will break string to two line on occurrence of space after 20 character.

```
dim inputstr as string = "This is my test input string. I hope it helps!"
dim breakafter as integer= 20
dim line1 as string,line2 as string
dim found as integer=InStr(breakafter, inputstr, " ", vbTextCompare) ' KNOW WHERE IS 1st space after 20 char(s)
line1= Left(inputstr,found )  ' get 1st part of text
line2 =  Replace(inputstr, " ", environment.newline() , found, 1, vbTextCompare) ' get remaining text 
msgbox line1 + iif(isnothing(line2),"",line2)
```